# Button setPressed for certain time period

Tags: android

I am trying to set a button state to pressed=true onTouch, and then have it set back to pressed=false after a certain time period.

The onTouch method properly sets the state to pressed

```
myTouchListener= new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            lastPressed = (Button)v; 
            lastPressed.setPressed(true);

           return true;
        }
    };
```

I then thought I could use a timer to set it back to original state. But a timer takes a TimerTask, which takes a runnable, so I can not pass it a reference to "lastPressed" button.

I am completely at a loss as where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually really easy,
create a final variable pointing to the same button, then you can use it in a thread,
and so start a new thread, which sets it false after a period of time:

```
myTouchListener= new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        lastPressed = (Button)v; 
        lastPressed.setPressed(true);

        final Button lp = lastPressed;
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); //your time in milliseconds here
                } catch (Exception e) { }

                lp.setPressed(false);
            }
        }
        t.start();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a message handler, and send a message from the timer task back to your activity, when the button state should be reset.

Note: The actual timing of TimerTask is known to be too inaccurate for many applications.

A better way, without using a TimerTask, would be to set up a message handler in your activity. Then after setting the button state to pressed, your activity can post a delayed message to itself to re-set the button state at the desired future time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to control the states of your button with onTouchEvent.

This is sample code:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;
     // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
     if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;
     doSomething();
     button.setPressed(true);                   
     return true;
     }
     });
```